# Modeling Traffic Patterns

Tags: trigonometry, mathematical-modeling

I am interested in modeling traffic flows as a function of time within an area (possibly using trig functions, but open to all methods). Consider the figure below, how would one approach solving this problem?

[image]

Comment: Does it have to be a trigonometric function? Perhaps it can be the sum of two Gaussians? (one for morning traffic and another for evening traffic)

Comment: The idea would be to create an application which generates events at that rate (number of vehicles per time unit) for the days of the week (with possible changes for weekend traffic) and have it executing continuously while also including some variance.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is just sampling a distribution given as a graph. Rejection sampling comes to mind.